# Переконвертация liniar-gradient в filter

Tags: css

мне нужно переконвертировать вот такой вот `gradient`

```
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(rgba(34, 34, 34, 0.62)), to(#2222221A));
```

в `filter`  , чтобы IE смог поддерживать этот overlay

Как то не получается. Я смотрел разные конвертёры, но там просто один цвет , а мне надо учитывать и сторону (left-right) ну и всё такое и два переходящих цвета. Из одного в другой

Comment: Зачем вам IE в 2020 году? Его используют менее 2% пользователей, лучше попросить их перейти на Firefox или Chrome.

Comment: Я об этом же , но меня уже закалибал клиент с IE , уже все долбят , поэтому и надо. Я соледарен с вашем мнением и так же сказал , меня чуть не уничтожили :D

Comment: Ну а вообще в IE11 нормально работает абсолютно стандартный `background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(34, 34, 34, 0.62) 0%, rgba(34, 34, 34, 0.1019) 100%);`

Comment: Более того, он работает даже в Firefox и Chrome, так что использовать `-webkit-gradient` вообще нет никакой необходимости

Comment: А клиент пусть платит дополнительную денежку за поддержку старых и немощных браузеров, кстати

Comment: Спасибо. Всё работает. 
п.с. кстати надо предложить такой варик насчет доп. денюжки :D

Comment: @Josef я просто отправляю все такие запросы в пешее эротическое путешествие